# Page Loading Problems - AJAX Related?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm running a test website for a bit for me and my friends to play around with before I roll it into my actual site.

One of the things this test website does is have a "feed" where users can insert text/images and etc. through a form.

I use AJAX for inserting content into the "feed" and also use it to refresh the feed.

However after a user plays with it for a while and posts stuff, they eventually can't post or load the page.

I'm a beginner to AJAX or whatever, but what is the cause of this? Is it AJAX related since I'm sending requests often? (10,000 ms too much?)

```
function WallPost() {
            REQUESTED_NAME = document.registerForm.NAME.value;
            REQUESTED_BODY = document.registerForm.BODY.value;
            if (!localStorage.name) {
                localStorage.name = REQUESTED_NAME;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/wall.php",
                data: "NAME=" + REQUESTED_NAME + "&BODY=" + REQUESTED_BODY + "&FORM=1&IP=i",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#registerMessage").append(msg);
                }
            });

            document.registerForm.BODY.value = "";

            RetrieveWall();
        }

        function RetrieveWall() {
            $.ajax( {
                url: "/getwall.php",
                success: function(msg2) {
                    $("#wall").html(msg2);  
                }
            });

            window.setTimeout("RetrieveWall()", 10000);
        }

        $.ajax( {
            url: "/getip.php",
            success: function(i) {
                IP = i;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Any code? I can't help you if you don't show me where the problem is ;)

Comment: Added some code.. Sorry for the weird formatting :S

Answer (score 0):

10 seconds seems fine, so I doubt the problem is the frequency.
To determine the true problem we would need either javascript console output and/or server logs.

Comment: I'd post this as a comment, as you aren't explicitly answering the OP's question.